# Recommend a Mac OS X Git GUI for comparing different commits side-by-side

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

I know that I can configure git to use an alternate diff tool, such as tkdiff, and that I can compare two arbitrary commits by entering them on the command line with "git diff commit# commit#".  Is there a free or inexpensive Mac OS X program that provides a GUI showing the commit network that lets me select which commits I want to compare?  The ability to do site-by-site diffs is important to me.  Unfortunately, the repo I'm working with is not well structured to work with Eclipse/EGit.

Answer (score 0):

XCode comes with opendiff/File Merge which works just fine. Github's Mac app will also works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I haven't been able to figure out how to view a side-by-side diff in the GitHub Mac app.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue isn't commit diffs.  The issue is how the diffs are displayed, whether on lines preceded by + and - or by the full lines being displayed side by side.

Comment: Well there are also quite a few other git GUIs, GitBox, Tower, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian has a free tool, [SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview). Very nice git GUI, and they are actively supporting and improving it. (I have no connection with Atlassian other than a user of this tool.)

There is also an open source tool called [GitX(L)](https://github.com/laullon/gitx.git), available on [github](https://github.com/laullon/gitx.git). I used this for quite a while, until I found SourceTree. It works well, too, but had a couple nuances that I finally got tired of. The difference between open source and commercially supported. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to SourceTree, although it also seems not to have side-by-side diff.  I was able to configure it to launch tkdiff, but I have to relaunch it for each file, which is not ideal for me.

Answer (score 0):

I like BeyondCompare, it's not free but it works intuitively exactly as I would expect it to. You can configure git to launch it with difftool or mergetool from the command line and compare local or GitHub files side-by-side.

I've used it in the past on Windows and I'm just about to buy it for MacOS